# Would questions about car washing or detailing be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, tags, topics

As the title. I took a look at the tags and didn't see one for it that I could find. While washing motor vehicles does tend to be a bit more unique than washing other things, it's not really dealing with any mechanical aspects of the vehicles in question. So, I thought I'd ask.

Would questions about car washing or detailing be on-topic?

Edit: I did my tag searching against car-wash and wash. After asking this, I discovered that the detailing tag does exist. So perhaps a better question is if we should create a car-wash tag and have it be a synonym for detailing. I would think the more casual user would more likely search for "car wash" while car enthusiasts may instead search for "detailing".

Comment: Well, it might fall into the category of "motor vehicle maintenance", but realy?  Having a site about how to wash your car?

Comment: @cullub: I'm not arguing for creating an entire site about car washing, although there are some that already exist. But I am contemplating asking some specific questions about washing my car, and these questions would be more than just your run-of-the-mill soap and water in a bucket variety. I'm just checking to see if they'd be a good fit. Considering the existence of the detailing tag, I assume the answer is yes, which is why I then ask if we should add some tag synonyms.

Comment: Ok, yeah.  Go ahead and ask them then!  I guess the worst that can happen is that they can get closed, but if they are mostly related, and interesting, they usually don't.

Comment: I guess I can't think of anything car-washing related that is non-intuitively-obvious...  Now I'm curious :)

Comment: [I hope they are!](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/26936/do-i-really-need-to-wash-the-outside-of-my-car)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There should be no worries about car care questions ... even washing the dirty beast. I think questions of the sort are *specifically* on target and on topic for this SE site. IMHO, it is definitely covered under the "maintenance" aspect of the site and it's about a motor vehicle. What more could you ask for! Ask away!

One small caveat is do not ask for specific product recommendations. You'd be looking to as how to get something done, not which wax is the best. How do you utilize a power buffer for best results. Stuff like that. Any questions about which products are best will surely be closed.

Comment: Any consideration about creating a car-wash tag and setting it as a synonym to detailing? The fact that I couldn't find a car-wash tag is what initially prompted this question.

Comment: I'm wondering if it is a little obscure. I don't know either way.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to say yes, maintenance of the outside of your car is on-topic just as much as the maintenance of the area under the hood, the inside of the cabin or any other piece attached to the vehicle.

Think about it: washing the car is much more complicated than just rinsing the dirt off the hood. For example, spraying the salt out of my underbody has contributed significantly to the fact that my car is still in one piece.

Admittedly, I'm biased here. A large part of my rep came from the answer to this question:

[Do I really need to wash the outside of my car?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/26936/57)

That answer is currently fourth in my feed (which I think is funny ;-).

Comment: And not spraying the salt out of my underbody has contributed significantly to the fact that my turbo heat shield barely still exists. But that's all being rectified soon.

Comment: @Bob ... haha! You say a large part of your rep ... nah ... Brother! You're the man and I *loved* that answer!!! Noice!